# Calling registerDevice with the old cordova ibm-mfp-push plugin gives an error message: "The notification was blocked by user"

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

This issue has already been reported [here](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push/issues/12).
It has been marked as solved, but unfortunately the problem is still present with the old version of the ibm-mfp-push plugin (1.0.13)

When calling `registerDevice` on iOS the very first time, the app prompts to accept/reject notifications. But regardless the user's answer, the failure callback is immediately fired with the message: "The notification was blocked by user".

Could you please help me to bypass this problem.
Unfortunately, upgrading to the latest bms-push version of the plugin is not a solution for me so far.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

This code block:

```
// Verify if user blocked the notifications
if (!self.hasPushEnabled()) {
    let message = "The notification was blocked by user"
    let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_ERROR, messageAsString: message)
    // call error callback
    self.commandDelegate!.sendPluginResult(pluginResult, callbackId:command.callbackId)
    return
}
```

has to be removed from the `registerDevice` function of the `CDVMFPPush.swift` class

As indicated in [this issue](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push/issues/12), someone from the dev team had removed it. But it apparently came back somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear you got it working! However, I do recommend upgrading to `bms-core` at some point as `ibm-mfp-core` will no longer be supported in the future.

Comment: I would love to upgrade :-) But as you noticed (ref other SO questions), I have some other problems with the new plugin version. As soon as I get answers to these questions, I will upgrade for sure.